# Looping through two directories in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have two directories with 50 files each (for example) that I need to compare sequentially.

Say dir1/file00 needs to be compared with dir2/file00, dir1/file01 with dir2/file01, dir1/file02 with dir2/file02 and so on.

I have a python script that does the comparison that I need to call within a shell script. How would I loop through these two directories and pass the files as arguments to the python script? I would need to pass the files in both directories sequentially to the script.

Sorry if this question has been asked before, I couldn't find a good solution anywhere and I'm pretty new to shellscripting.

Comment: Why write anything, that's what `diff` is for, e.g. `diff -uN dir1 dir2`. (see options `-Z`, `-b`, `-w` , `-B` for whitespace control)

Comment: @SHA : How do you want to treat files which are in only one of the directory, but not in the other? What is the desired effect if there are subdirectories?

Comment: @user1934428 The files follow a numbering system, so that would be handled at the start. They're computer generated files so there's little chance of them missing out, and its not something I need to worry about at the moment. Either way, I ended up using brace expansion and it fulfilled my purpose :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I actually did end up using diff at the end to compare the files in each directory! But since I needed to print out a report of sorts of the differences in each text file, I had to resort to calling another script that contained that part of code with the files themselves as command line arguments.

Comment: @SHA : Don't forget that brace expansion is pretty fixed. If you have one day 51 files, you have to edit your script. Given your regular numbering, a wildcard pattern `file[0-9][0-9]` would be more flexible (allows up to 99 files at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways. If you know the names ahead of time, [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```sh
for num in {00..49}; do
    compare "dir1/file$num" "dir2/file$num"
done
```

If the upper limit is in a variable, a C-like [for loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#index-for) might be more appropriate:

```sh
maxfile=49
for (( i = 0; i <= maxfile; i++ )); do
  printf -v file "file%02d" $i # Assign to variable instead of printing
  compare "dir1/$file" "dir2/$file"
done
```

Comment: Brace expansion was the answer I was looking for! Thank you for the help!